# How to call method or emit event to parent component from a slotted component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

This is my template

```html
<template>
  <some-component>
    <button>Hello!</button>
  </some-component>
</template>
```

This is my component (some-component)

```html
<template>
  <slot />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    someMethod() {
      // Does something
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How would I go about calling `someMethod()` from the button that is slotted into the component, or otherwise, emit an event that `some-component` can listen to, to run the method itself from the button slotted in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `someMethod` as a slot prop of `some-component`:

```html
<template>
  <slot :onClick="someMethod" />
</template>
```

Then the parent that uses `some-component` could bind the slot prop to the `button`:

```html
<some-component>
  <template v-slot="{ onClick }">
    <button @click="onClick">Click me</button>
  </template>
</some-component>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-method-slot-prop?file=src/App.vue)